# Working with unknown object types?

Tags: c#, .net

I am wanting to get the average of a column. I can get it working like:

```
           IEnumerable results = defaultView.Select(args);
           Decimal amount = results.Cast<Fees>().Average(x => x.Fee);
```

where results is a collection of System.Collections.Generic.List`1 objects. However results is not always the same  object because something else may be returned.

It is always in the structure of x objects with 5-10 values each.

I was hoping for a generic way to iterate over the data such as results[0][2] but can't find a way to access this data without using the strongly typed example above. Any ideas?

Comment: you could cast them to a ```dynamic```, but why forgo the type safety?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to create interfaces for the properties that are shared amongst different classes:

```
public interface IHasFee
{
  decimal Fee {get;}
}
```

Then you could apply this interface to all the classes that have a Fee property:

```
public class Fees : IHasFee
{
  public decimal Fee {get;set;}
}


public class Charge : IHasFee
{
  public decimal Fee {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to iterate through objects of certain type (for example `Fees`) in a collection that may contain objects of different types, try using: [Enumerable.OfType Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) .

```
IEnumerable results = defaultView.Select(args);
Decimal amount = results.OfType<Fees>().Average(x => x.Fee);
```

From MSDN:

> **Enumerable.OfType Method**
>
> Filters the elements of an IEnumerable based on a specified type.
>
> The OfType(IEnumerable) method returns only those elements in
>   source that can be cast to type TResult. To instead receive an
>   exception if an element cannot be cast to type TResult, use
>   Cast(IEnumerable).